# Travis android script

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm starting to configure CI into my project. I'm not sure what some gradle commands do, I would like to be sure if all my tests are running, unit and instrumentation.

I think to run unit test I must use `test` or `check`, Am I correct? or does `connectedCheck` run unit tests?

To ensure both of them are executed I have this Travis script:

```
script:
  - ./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport
  - ./gradlew check -PdisablePreDex --continue --stacktrace
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - ./gradlew connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --continue --stacktrace
```

You can see complete file on https://github.com/zalito12/common-request

I think it's ok now, but I would like to be sure, thanks.